# Need help saving HD video stream to file

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm using libstreaming.

I would like to initiate two `MediaCodec`s with different settings and bitrates (one low quality - which will be transmitted via HTTP and one high to be saved to the SDCARD).

The problem appears to be that I can't grab two separate Mediacodec objects with differing settings.

The high bitrate version is saved as a video containing nothing but a green background *unless the dimensions are set to < 352x288, however the low bitrate version is successfully (and correctly) being streamed to the web.

I am really hoping that I'm doing something obviously wrong and that there's a simple way to save the HD version of the stream to disk.

[image: code block where I initiate the MediaCodecs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this should work on most devices - I do it without a problem on a number of devices.

But there are some devices where the encoder driver has got restrictions for this - in particular, some Intel devices refuse to create a second encoder instance while one is active. (Samsung Galaxy Note 3 10.1 comes to mind - not sure if all other Intel based ones have the same issue, or only some of them.)

Unfortunately, even if the Android CTS tests have tests to ensure that the hardware encoder works, there's no test that guarantees that you can have more than one encoder active at the same time.

Does your case fail only if you have differing settings on the second encoder, or also if they have the same settings?

If one stream is of a low resolution, you could try using a SW encoder for that instead, while using the HW encoder for the high resolution version. On Android 6.0, the SW encoder `OMX.google.h264.encoder` should be quite decent, while on older versions, it's close to unusable.

Comment: Thanks very much... will follow your advice and report back.  In answer to your question about the case failure - yes - it only seems to fail when the settings are different. The local version saves correctly when the resolution is less than some (pretty small) number.

Comment: Hmm, right. Care to tell what device this is, and what resolution combinations work and which don't? It can also be some sort of restriction on total memory available to the encoder HW. E.g. if you at max can encode one stream of 1080p, you might be able to encode 720p + a low res one, as long as the total memory usage of them both doesn't exceed what a  single 1080p stream uses.